# SQL Server 2008 + VB6 Limit Stored Procedure Access

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6

Is there a way I can limit the number of computers which can access or run a stored procedure at the same time?

For example, I have an application installed on 10 different locations. I want only five locations to be able to run the stored procedure. The other five will receive a notification if they try to access the sp.

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a table that contains a 'run_id' and an 'is_active' column. On every start, the sp picks a new id and sets 'is_active' to true, till the sp is done. The next sp will check if 'count(is_active)' is smaller 11(where is_active = true). I think that will do the job

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why you need to do this, because without understanding your goal it isn't clear what solution would be most appropriate.

Comment: @stb One issue with that solution is that if the application crashes or loses its connection to SQL Server while the procedure is executing, then the flag will not be reset. [Application locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823(v=sql.100).aspx) are one way to avoid that situation (transactions could help too) but it isn't clear why the OP wants to do this or how his procedure behaves.

Comment: @Pondlife Hm true. But don't you have the same problem, because you have to use sp_releaseapplock, too?

Comment: I want to use it for stored procedures that take a lot of time to complete. In order not to overload the server or the network, when a bunch of result data is to be returned.

Comment: @stb No, because an application lock is handled like any other lock, i.e. if the session ends for any reason the lock is released automatically by the system.

Comment: @JeromeBuquing What does "a lot of time" mean? Seconds, minutes, hours? And how much is a "bunch" of data? Long-running processes might be better handled by queuing or scheduling the requests, rather than calling the procedure directly from the application. You might also consider upgrading your hardware as a cheaper, easier alternative to developing a solution, but of course only if you know for sure that hardware is a limiting factor.